# How to set up python program that takes input from sensors and analyzes it?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, buffer, sensors

I am collecting data from a DFRobot Gravity Analog Heart Monitor Sensor with a five lead system into a Rapsberry Pi. I am using python to generate the program. How do I create a timer and a data buffer to store this data on an sd card?

Comment: I don’t know much about sensors, You can try to check the sensor documentation. And if you tried any post the code here.

Answer (score 0):

your question is quite vague, I don't think the GPIO of the raspberry pi has an analog input. You'll need a Analgo to digital converter such as https://www.adafruit.com/product/1085
This link will actually be quite useful for you as it will introduce Circuitpython from adafruit https://circuitpython.org/ which will help you out in controlling sensors and other circuits with python.